# Need ideas for Chess Non-Random move response in Python

Tags: python, chess

I'm trying to work out in Python (Pygame) how to make black play a pre-programmed line of moves in response to what white plays (like playing through a past player's game, or playing opening lines only as one color). I'm new to coding and while resources have helped me understand creating a chess engine and its UI, I can't find any resources which help implementing a **NON**-random move generating chess AI.

Can anyone point me in the right direction or the simplest logic? Right now my noob code doesn't work as the only thing I could come up with myself is to create an *if* statement for moving the first white pawn, where the corresponding black pawn moves down two squares, etc. but it's not efficient at all if to play out a whole game. Thanks!

Comment: Read this : https://www.chessprogramming.org/Getting_Started

Comment: For a well explained chess-engine in Python and JavaScript, I've made this one (https://github.com/PaulJeFi/reglisse-chess) with many comments to explain everything in details.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of pre-generated games. For instance games imported from a PGN:

```py
games = [
    "1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bb5", # Ruy Lopez
    "1. d4 d5 2. c4", # Queen's gambit
    "1. e4 d5", # Scandinavian defense
]
```

You can then parse these games into a structure that is easier to work with.
Eg:

```py
parsed_game = [("e4", "e5"), ("Nf3","Nc6"), ("Bb5", "")]
```

Let's take the example where you play d4 1st move. The program will check the game in your array where your first move is d4. Here it is the Queen's gambit game. It will then play d5 and wait for you to play c4.

In case there is a branch (in the case you play e4 first for example), you can decide how the program will handle the game choice.

- You can decide to pick the game with the lowest indexin the list.
- You can decide to let the player decide which game to play (using UI).
- You can set the played game before the program starts.

Answer (score 0):

Moving a player according to a predefined sequence is easy enough: Just hard-code a list of **positions** (e.g. `['A2 to A4', 'A4 to A5', 'E3 to F4']`) or a list of **moves** (e.g. `['A2 two up', 'A4 one up', 'E3 one up, one right']`), and move according to the list. Of course this requires some translation of positions/moves to *actual* movements on the board.

The difficulity is, as you mentioned, that your program might want to play differently depending on how white moves. From an abstract point of view: You need something that takes the **current state of the game** as an **input** and gives a **move for the black player** as an **output**.

There are many ways to achieve this. One solution would be to **roll a dice** each time, but you specifically asked for *no randomness*. Another solution is to train an **AI**.

Thirdly, you could write some **logic** that determines the next move. Writing lots of `if` statements like you tried leads to messy code quickly, so you have to be smart about it and split your code into functions. For example:

1. A function that gets a *starting position*, a *destination* and a *movement rule* (e.g. 'can only move up') as arguments and returns the shortest path to get from start to destination using only legal moves
2. A function that uses function `1` to determine which *black* chess piece can reach a *white* chess piece in the *least number of steps*
3. A function that gets a *number of steps* as an argument and returns a set of positions where a *white* chess piece could *be* after given amount of steps

... and so on. There are infinitely more ways you could evaluate a chess game state. Finally you need to combine your functions so that you get a *single* move and chess piece as an output.

Comment: Actually all of this is bad idea, excepted for the predefined lines of play, called opening book. Training a neural network for chess is generally a bad idea for a beginner. And making "a lot of if statements" is clearly a bad idea, because chess is more complex than saying "if this, do that".
The good stuff to start with, especially for a beginner, is a nagamaw alpha-beta with a quiescence search and a basic evaluation function, like PeSTO's one. All of this could be found in chess programming wiki (chessprogramming.org).